# How to parse this JSON object in Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

### JSON:

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "title": "BlahBlahBlah #1",
      "session_num": "369",
      "author": "Lilyquist J",
      "tradeshow": "AACR General Meeting 2017",
      "show_details": [
        {
          "date": "April 1-5, 2017",
          "location": "Washington DC"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "YaddaYaddaYadda #2",
      "session_num": "369",
      "author": "Lilyquist J",
      "tradeshow": "Epcon 97",
      "show_details": [
        {
          "date": "April 1-5, 1997",
          "location": "Anywhere, CA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "BlahBlahBlah #3",
      "session_num": "369",
      "author": "LaDuca H",
      "tradeshow": "(ACMG) 2017",
      "show_details": [
        {
          "date": "April 1-5, 2017",
          "location": "Washington DC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Symfony Controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/route", name="ag_web_route")
     * @Template()
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function scientificPosters2Action()
    {
        $posterList = file_get_contents($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/assets/api/scientific-posters.json');

        $json = json_decode($posterList, true);

        foreach ($json['details'] as $key => $value) {
            echo $value['title'];
        }

        return array(
            'json' => $json,
            'posterList' => $posterList,
        );
    }
```

### Twig:

```
{% for title in posterList %}
    <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

#### My Final Result of the above code looks like:

BlahBlahBlah #1YaddaYaddaYadda #2BlahBlahBlah #3

I haven't been able to forloop correctly and only output one Title at a time. It just outputs all of the titles together into one `<h1>` tag. What am I missing here? I know that the `$key` => `$value` I have is missing something, (like another forloop?) but I haven't been able to parse this correctly...

Using Symfony3 here.

Comment: Hi there. Did my answer solve the problem? If so please click the checkmark by the answer to mark it as correct; if not, please comment as to what else you might need help with. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the Title, it would be like this:

```
<h1> {{ json['details']['title'] }} </h1>
```

If you read up about it on my [JSON Twig article](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/04/18/simplified-web-development-with-json-and-the-twig-ternary-operator/), that might help you achieve what you need.

---

EDIT #2

Based on comments, if there is a problem with the for loop, you can try this:

```
{% for item in json['details'] %}
    <h1> {{ item['title'] }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is a twigfiddle showing it works properly as you need and specified:

https://twigfiddle.com/ua9ebs

Make sure you are passing the JSON from Controller to twig template using php function `json_decode` for this to work properly. It should be straightforward.

Comment: it didn't work in this case, but I am trying to apply your article to my issue now however.

Comment: Is it the for loop you need help with? Maybe I can update my answer....